# Help with Searchkit query on Non members

Tags: searchkit

Hopefully very easy but I want to build a search kit of people in a mailing group (Historic Event Attendees) who are NOT current members.

When I do Status = Empty, I get 378,

but when I do Status = Does not Include New, Current, Renewal, Grace, I only get 40!

Please can you suggest what extra query I need to add to get this to show me people in the group who are NOT current members, as I should get more in the second query, as that would include those with status lapsed and cancelled.

[image: Search Filter]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have made Join as 'With(optional)' and with status empty will give you contacts who never had membership

If you do OR clause then you should get 378+40 results approx with group by

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Pradeep!

Comment: You can also change the join from "With" to "Without"!